# clang and gcc disagree on the type of conditional expression with xvalues

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14, conditional-operator

I made a little test with the conditional operator to see the computed type of two object with same underlying type (same type when removing references and cv-qualifiers). GCC and clang++ agree in every combination (I have not test `volatiles`), except with xvalues:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct A {};

template<class A>
void print_qualif()
{
    using rm_r = std::remove_reference_t<A>;

    if (std::is_const<rm_r>::value)
        std::cout << "const";

    if (std::is_lvalue_reference<A>::value)
        std::cout << '&';
    else if (std::is_rvalue_reference<A>::value)
        std::cout << "&&";
    std::cout << "  ";
}

#define res(X, Y) print_qualif<decltype(true ? X : Y)>()

A&& x();
A const&& xc();

int&& ix();
int const&& ixc();

int main()
{
    res(x(), xc()); // GCC prints const&& and clang const
    res(ix(), ixc()); // Both prints const&&
}
```

Who is right? I will say GCC is right here because, when both operands have same value category and same underlying type, they keep the result keep the value category with the cv-qualifiers of the most qualified.

Comment: clang bug, fixed in 3.9.